# How do I find this button with selenium and then click it after I do the recpatcha?

Tags: python, html, selenium

Filling out a form, doing the recaptcha and then pressing submit. For whatever reason I can't "find" the element with selenium. Here's the element:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-lg submit-hide" data-event-label="Contactemail_SubmitButton">Send Email
                        </button>
```

I've tried:

```
1.) submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Send Email"]').click()
2.) submit = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Send Email').click()
3.) submit = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Send Email').click()
4.) submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains()="Send Email"]').click()
5.) submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="profile-contact"]/div[7]/div/button').click()
and other similar variations
```

How do I do this? Do I need to get out of the iframe for the recaptcha before I hit submit?

Comment: yes get out the captcha frame

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return from iframe with

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```